# Plotting multiple series of a dataframe in one graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataframe is called `covid_df` and I'm trying to plot both cases and deaths on one single graph and I can't figure out how to do it yet.

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

covid_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
covid_df.new_cases.plot()
covid_df.new_deaths.plot()
plt.show()
```

After executing this code, all I get is a plot of one series and not both. How do I make Python take both into consideration on one single graph?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually plotting using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) and not matplotlib. Instead try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
covid_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
plt.plot(covid_df.new_cases)
plt.plot(covid_df.new_deaths)
plt.show()
```